# Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: io.fabric8.kubernetes.api.model.AuthInfo.getExec()Lio/fabric8/kubernetes/api/model/ExecConfig;

Tags: java, apache-spark, kubernetes, nosuchmethoderror, fabric8

I am following this tutorial on running Spark-Pi application on a kubernetes cluster https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/running-on-kubernetes.html#cluster-mode

When I submit this command,

```
> --master k8s://https://138.1.55.60:6443 \
> --deploy-mode cluster \
> --name spark-pi \
> --class org.apache.spark.examples.SparkPi \
> --conf spark.executor.instances=1 \
> --conf spark.kubernetes.container.image=iad.ocir.io/idfoaqwbw7ew/raghav_images/sparkline:v1_spark-2.4.3 \
> local:///opt/spark/examples/jars/spark-examples_2.11-2.4.3.jar
```

I get this exception

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: io.fabric8.kubernetes.api.model.AuthInfo.getExec()Lio/fabric8/kubernetes/api/model/ExecConfig;
```

Here is the backtrace:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: io.fabric8.kubernetes.api.model.AuthInfo.getExec()Lio/fabric8/kubernetes/api/model/ExecConfig;
    at io.fabric8.kubernetes.client.Config.loadFromKubeconfig(Config.java:536)
    at io.fabric8.kubernetes.client.Config.tryKubeConfig(Config.java:487)
    at io.fabric8.kubernetes.client.Config.autoConfigure(Config.java:223)
    at io.fabric8.kubernetes.client.Config.<init>(Config.java:207)
    at io.fabric8.kubernetes.client.ConfigBuilder.<init>(ConfigBuilder.java:16)
    at io.fabric8.kubernetes.client.ConfigBuilder.<init>(ConfigBuilder.java:13)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.k8s.SparkKubernetesClientFactory$.createKubernetesClient(SparkKubernetesClientFactory.scala:66)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.k8s.submit.KubernetesClientApplication$$anonfun$run$4.apply(KubernetesClientApplication.scala:221)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.k8s.submit.KubernetesClientApplication$$anonfun$run$4.apply(KubernetesClientApplication.scala:221)
    at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.tryWithResource(Utils.scala:2588)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.k8s.submit.KubernetesClientApplication.run(KubernetesClientApplication.scala:227)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.k8s.submit.KubernetesClientApplication.start(KubernetesClientApplication.scala:192)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.org$apache$spark$deploy$SparkSubmit$$runMain(SparkSubmit.scala:894)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.doRunMain$1(SparkSubmit.scala:198)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.submit(SparkSubmit.scala:228)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.main(SparkSubmit.scala:137)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.main(SparkSubmit.scala)
2020-03-21 18:13:21 INFO  ShutdownHookManager:54 - Shutdown hook called
2020-03-21 18:13:21 INFO  ShutdownHookManager:54 - Deleting directory /private/var/folders/c4/0wrtptlj4hb285lhyh214_hm0000gn/T/spark-1fe922e6-22c5-445a-9645-9f9918ca6e0c
```

Any help how to resolve this?

Comment: `NoSuchMethodError` always means you are mixing versions of that library somewhere.

Comment: Hi @chrylis-onstrike- Thanks for taking a look.  I am not sure which library versions I am mixing up. Could you be more verbose?

Comment: The library providing `AuthInfo`. Presumably your image or some other tool comes with a version of the k8s client, and another tool or your code has an incompatible version.

Comment: Have you built Spark with Maven before building Docker image? Can you share your build command? You need to build Spark with [Kubernetes support](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/building-spark.html#building-with-kubernetes-support) and then build [Spark Docker image](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/running-on-kubernetes.html#docker-images). Did you do any customizations on that flow?

Comment: In my case it was different versions of io.fabric8.kubernetes-client and io.fabric8.kubernetes-model. I had different setup - springboot project, but the exception was the same. Solution was to specify versions of both dependencies in pom.xml. This resulted in classpath change and it worked.